# How do I prove the following theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $F$ is a field and $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $f(x)$ has no repeated roots if and only if $(f, f') = 1$, where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Suppose $f(x) = (x- \alpha)^m g(x), m \geq 2$ then $f'(\alpha) = 0.$ On the other hand, let $f(x) = (x - \alpha)h(x)$ and $f'(\alpha) = 0.$ Then show that $f(x) = (x - \alpha)^2h_1(x).$

Comment: The notation $h'(x)$ could cause confusion if it is not a derivative.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I didn't realize it. Now changed. Thanks.